# What should I do when my supervisor refuses to write a recommendation letter for applications to institutions outside my country?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, professorship, recommendation-letter, authorship

I want to apply for a PhD position in country X. My supervisor lives in country Y and wants me to apply only in Y. He is the corresponding author of my 4-5 publications. He said if I want to apply for any other country apart from Y, he would not write a LOR for me. In this case, what should I do?

Also, can a co-author of my 2/3 publication can recommend me? (She's a post doc.)

Comment: Not crucial, but you currently in country Y or X?  And will he not write a letter for applications to country Y if your also apply to country X, or just will send a letter to country Y but not X?

Comment: I am In country Y. He will write only for Y.

Comment: For the latter question, yes, others can write for you, but probably with less impact under the circumstances.

Comment: Similar question: [My advisor refuses to write me a recommendation for my PhD application unless I apply to his lab](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79021/my-advisor-refuses-to-write-me-a-recommendation-for-my-phd-application-unless-i?rq=1)

Comment: @BlackSheep: This seems to be really bizarre. Two comments, if I may: (1) Currently, the question in the title is different from the question in the post itself - it might thus be worthwhile to adjust the title. [...]

Comment: [...] (2) What confuses me is that, according to your profile, you're currently located in Germany. But in my experience, letters of reccomendation are very uncommon inside German academia - so your supervisor position that he'll only write you a letter of recommendation if you apply in Germany is (on top of being unethical) somehow pointless - it's not very likely (though not impossible) that you would actually need such a letter for an application in Germany. (Obviously, this does not solve your problem since you want to apply outside Germany - but I find it confusing anyway.)

Comment: I am not in Germany anymore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ask someone else.  Anyone you ask to write an LOR is free to decide whether or not to do it for any reason of their choosing or even for no reason at all.  But if they don't want to do it, somehow pressuring them into doing it anyway is unlikely to result in a really positive letter that's going to be of any help.  Asking someone to write an LOR for you is pretty quick way to find out what someone thinks of you.  If they decline, you got your answer and you need to move on.

Realistically, not all that many people get along all that great with their supervisors or want to share their plans with them, especially if that's why they're leaving.  (In industry, the popular adage is that no one leaves a bad job, they leave a bad manager.) It's a common experience everyone has sooner or later, so it's unlikely anyone will ever think it's odd if your LORs come from other people.

Unless the person writing your LOR is exceptionally well-known, it's usually far more important what the letter says, e.g., the nature and detail in the observations being reported in support of the recommendation, than who signed it.  Best to find people who are unreserved in their willingness to help you -- then help them with whatever info they might find helpful, e.g., your transcripts, CV, any essays you'll submit, etc., so they can write a really good letter.

Comment: I think you’re skirting the issue that there can be misguided, and/or unethical, reasons for not agreeing to write a letter. In the “misguided” scenario, it’s possible that a bit of discussion, and gentle pressure from colleagues, might make the person see the error of their ways, leading to a positive letter-writing outcome. I wouldn’t just give up as a default action in that situation. And in the case of blatantly unethical (e.g., racist or sexist) reasons, while I agree that it’s unwise to insist on a letter, one can still complain, hopefully leading to misconduct charges against the prof.

Comment: @DanRomik If you can convince them on your own without a lot of pushing, I guess that could work.  It's hard for me to imagine most faculty would appreciate other faculty being drawn into a disagreement with a student over whether to write an LOR. When someone declines to write an LOR for any reason or no reason, I stand by my advice: You need to move on and ask someone else.  But that's just my opinion.  Anyone is free to differ, make their own choices and see what happens.

Comment: The only concern I have is it should not raise a red flag to the admission committee/the graduate school in my application.

Comment: I don't think that's a big risk.  I think most people are aware that people sometimes decline to write LORs for all kinds of reasons that may have nothing to do with the quality of the candidate and that candidates sometimes don't ask for LORs from certain people for personal reasons.  Best to find people who are unreserved in their willingness to help you -- then help them with whatever info they might find helpful, e.g., your transcripts, CV, any essays you'll submit, etc., so they can write a really good letter.

Comment: @BlackSheep It may be country-dependent. In some countries LORs are a formality, you have to have them but they are not too important, in such countries the letter from other co-authors or other professors is fine. It worked for me. If your country X takes them more seriously, you may need to explain it at the interview but I would not draw attention to it in my application. Also, try to get a LOR from a professor or collaborator with ties to country X instead.

Answer (score 14):

Ask him to explain himself, and try to reason with him. His behavior sounds unethical and abusive. It is not for him to decide which country you should live in and get your PhD in. Consider getting one of his colleagues or the department chair to talk to him and advocate for you in a diplomatic way, without applying too much pressure. They may be in a better position to explain to him how wrong such behavior is. Perhaps he is a decent person who simply has some misguided ideas, and following such a conversation will change his mind and all will be well.

But, sadly, if he persists in his refusal, there isn’t much point in trying to force his hand. In that case, you can consider explaining the reason why you are not including a letter from him in your applications to programs in other countries. It is a strange enough reason that I’m guessing people will accept it at face value and not question your sincerity. Of course, you’ll still need to have good letters from other people; get the best ones that you can. If they are good and written by people who have worked with you, you will be fine. Good luck!

Comment: It might be useful to hear his reasoning, if any. Some reasons might have some validity, though I agree completely with this answer.

Comment: @Buffy can you give an example of a valid reason? I try to keep an open mind, but in this case I cannot imagine an ethical reason to deny someone a letter of reference based on the country where they want to apply.

Comment: The one that first came to mind was a worry that the student would find it hard to be accepted in a different country/culture for some reason. Another, less valid, would be that the prof really thinks the person would be an asset in the future to the academic culture of their own country. The conversation you suggest would be valuable to have.

Comment: @Buffy ok, thanks. I disagree that any of those are valid reasons to deny the letter. It’s not the professor’s life, and not his decision where the student should apply.

Comment: I agree, but think it still valuable to hear them, if they exist.

Comment: I'll also note that having them write a letter "under duress" could result in a terrible outcome. There are a lot of ways to sabotage a student. Someone sensible and with authority might need to approve any such letter. I once got "sabotaged" inadvertently and unintentionally by a poor choice of wording. It led to a deep misunderstanding of my potential. I only learned of it many years later.

Comment: @Buffy agreed, that’s what I meant about not forcing his hand. But if after a conversation with the department chair he shows signs of understanding that sabotaging his student in such a way is inappropriate, I’d say it’s fine to have him write the letter. If the chair suspects he might try to pull off something underhanded, the chair can ask to see the letter, but hopefully that won’t be necessary.

Comment: I really doubt most faculty will react positively to a student complaint to the dept chair that they refused to write an LOR.  The ones I work with aren't that easy-going.

Comment: @DanRomik If the OP is unfortunate enough the department chair might be even more passionate about keeping the student in their country... This can be tricky to navigate overall.

Comment: @Lodinn sounds like you’re [catastrophizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catastrophize). For any proposed course of action one can imagine extremely unlikely but still possible scenarios leading to a bad outcome. That doesn’t mean my advice doesn’t represent the overall most sensible course of action.

Comment: It really, really depends. IMHO it'd be prudent to gather some info about whether it's an isolated case or is the entire department like that. You seem to operate under assumptions that 1) It's widely considered unethical and 2) Something this blatant won't be tolerated and one could get outside help. I've seen both of them violated more than once - thankfully, it's quite niche. In general, I'd say your advice is *probably* solid but it *can* backfire really badly if one misses a few cues...

Comment: @Lodinn yes, some prudence is warranted obviously. But in the overwhelmingly most likely scenario, if the chair agrees with the professor, OP will be no worse than before. It’s worth a shot. My only assumptions are what my life experience has taught me, that most people are pretty decent, and with the ones who aren’t, it’s usually reasonably easy to tell that that’s the case. Of course if OP senses that they’re dealing with unscrupulous people then they should choose the safe option and simply ask someone else for a letter.

Comment: @DanRomik: Just to play Devil's advocate, if a PhD candidature is subsidised by the govt. of the host country, the advisor might take the view that some subsequent work in the same country is an ethical requirement to "give back" to the hapless taxpayers that subsidised the degree.  Whether that circumstance applies depends on the particular country and its education-subsidies, but it is a possible basis for this view.  It may be a bit tenuous, but that could be a valid reason for the attitude.

Comment: @Ben ok, as I said to Buffy I don’t find your proposed hypothetical reason “valid” (i.e., ethical). The professor can legitimately be of the _opinion_ that OP should apply for a PhD in the same country, but he cannot ethically use his power to deny writing a letter to sabotage OP’s applications in other countries. That crosses a clear ethical boundary into an unethical abuse of power.

Comment: I don't agree that not writing a letter is an abuse of power --- it is a somewhat odd decision, and I don't agree with it, but no-one is under any obligation to write letters of recommendation.